# Reformat Git Clone Progress with Pipe

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe

I'm using a script to deploy git code. I have a function that I use to format the progress:

```
log ()
{
    d=$(date "+%Y%m%d %H%M%S.%4N")
    echo "[$d] $1"
}
```

I have tried to understand other articles/posts regarding piping git clone, but only see posts that address piping to a file.

Here is what I have:

```
git clone --progress $api_repository 2>&1 | log
```

Clearly not working as it does not pass the value as a parameter to log (output only shows a date - and only one).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT (sample git clone output):

```
Cloning into 'apicode'...
remote: Counting objects: 515, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (414/414), done.
remote: Total 515 (delta 275), reused 234 (delta 76)
Receiving objects: 100% (515/515), 70.82 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (275/275), done.
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is to get output like so:

```
[20170511 161944.1041] Cloning into 'apicode'...
[20170511 161944.1241] remote: Counting objects: 515, done.
[20170511 161944.1341] remote: Compressing objects: 100% (414/414), done.
[20170511 161944.1441] remote: Total 515 (delta 275), reused 234 (delta 76)
[20170511 161944.1541] Receiving objects: 100% (515/515), 70.82 KiB, done.
[20170511 161944.1641] Resolving deltas: 100% (275/275), done.
```

(basically adding a timestamp to each line)

Comment: Can you please add some example of what output you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is what I have:
>
> ```
> git clone --progress $api_repository 2>&1 | log
> ```
>
> Clearly not working as it does not pass the value as a parameter to
>   log (output only shows a date - and only one).

First of all, this is not working because `log` function does not take the string from stdin, but rather its command line parameter `$1` — which is empty in this case. So it runs only once on no input, hence just showing you the date.

The usual approach to applying `log` to every line of another program's output is by wrapping it with [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs). For [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to be able to call what is defined as a shell function, you would need to first make a script file out of it (say `./log.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$(date "+%Y%m%d %H%M%S.%4N")
echo "[$d] $1"
```

Then, you would call [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) like this:

```
git clone --progress https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git 2>&1 |
    xargs -n1 -d'\n' ./log.sh
```

…Alas, this also doesn't work as expected.

---

Here's the option to `git clone` you want to use:

```
--progress
       Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default
       when it is attached to a terminal, unless -q is specified. This flag
       forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not
       directed to a terminal.
```

The reason progress status is not reported when standard error is not attached to a terminal, and also because the simple approach to your problem fails short, is this:

```
0000000: 436c 6f6e 696e 6720 696e 746f 2027 6c69  Cloning into 'li
0000010: 6e75 7827 2e2e 2e0a 7265 6d6f 7465 3a20  nux'....remote: 
0000020: 436f 756e 7469 6e67 206f 626a 6563 7473  Counting objects
0000030: 3a20 3533 3739 3436 3020 2020 2020 2020  : 5379460       
0000040: 2020 2020 0d72 656d 6f74 653a 2043 6f75      .remote: Cou
0000050: 6e74 696e 6720 6f62 6a65 6374 733a 2035  nting objects: 5
0000060: 3338 3838 3534 2c20 646f 6e65 2e20 2020  388854, done.   
0000070: 2020 2020 200a 7265 6d6f 7465 3a20 436f       .remote: Co
0000080: 6d70 7265 7373 696e 6720 6f62 6a65 6374  mpressing object
0000090: 733a 2020 2030 2520 2831 2f37 3931 3429  s:   0% (1/7914)
00000a0: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 200d 7265 6d6f             .remo
00000b0: 7465 3a20 436f 6d70 7265 7373 696e 6720  te: Compressing 
00000c0: 6f62 6a65 6374 733a 2020 2031 2520 2838  objects:   1% (8
00000d0: 302f 3739 3134 2920 2020 2020 2020 2020  0/7914)         
00000e0: 2020 0d72 656d 6f74 653a 2043 6f6d 7072    .remote: Compr
00000f0: 6573 7369 6e67 206f 626a 6563 7473 3a20  essing objects: 
20000100: 2020 3225 2028 3135 392f 3739 3134 2920    2% (159/7914)
```

This is what the program on the other end of the pipe is seeing. `git` is using [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character (`0d` or `\r`) to update the counters in the progress output. When interpreted by a terminal, carriage return moves the cursor to the beginning of a line, effectively overwriting the prefix `log` is trying to insert. But worse, if you're redirecting to a file, your log will contain all the intermediate stuff which will take tens to thousands of times more space than the final output.

So really what this means is that you must filter out all the intermediate progress strings if you're only interested in the final output:

```
git clone --progress https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git 2>&1 |
    sed 's:.*\r::' |
    xargs -n1 -d'\n' ./log.sh
```

This will remove carriage return-terminated substrings before piping into `log`. Here's the output:

```
[20170512 002119.3233] Cloning into 'linux'...
[20170512 002119.3264] remote: Counting objects: 277, done.        
[20170512 002119.3289] remote: Total 277 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 274        
[20170512 002119.3310] Receiving objects: 100% (277/277), 56.33 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
[20170512 002119.3331] Resolving deltas: 100% (155/155), done.
```

For a more interactive (and verbose) version, replace `\r` with `\n` instead. The following uses [tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
git clone --progress https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git 2>&1 |
    tr '\r' '\n' |
    xargs -n1 -d'\n' ./log.sh
```

Which result in the following:

```
[20170511 234551.3756] Cloning into 'linux'...
[20170511 234551.3806] remote: Counting objects: 5379460           
[20170511 234551.3854] remote: Counting objects: 5388854, done.        
[20170511 234551.3898] remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/7914)           
[20170511 234551.3941] remote: Compressing objects:   1% (80/7914)           
[20170511 234551.3979] remote: Compressing objects:   2% (159/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4019] remote: Compressing objects:   3% (238/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4066] remote: Compressing objects:   4% (317/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4108] remote: Compressing objects:   5% (396/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4132] remote: Compressing objects:   6% (475/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4155] remote: Compressing objects:   7% (554/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4183] remote: Compressing objects:   8% (634/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4208] remote: Compressing objects:   9% (713/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4231] remote: Compressing objects:  10% (792/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4254] remote: Compressing objects:  11% (871/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4277] remote: Compressing objects:  12% (950/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4300] remote: Compressing objects:  13% (1029/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4323] remote: Compressing objects:  14% (1108/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4346] remote: Compressing objects:  15% (1188/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4381] remote: Compressing objects:  16% (1267/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4408] remote: Compressing objects:  17% (1346/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4432] remote: Compressing objects:  18% (1425/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4456] remote: Compressing objects:  19% (1504/7914)           
[20170511 234551.4480] remote: Compressing objects:  20% (1583/7914)
```

Comment: This is a great response and thanks for the time you put in explaining the problem. Question for you, you seem to still be exporting to a file (log.sh)? Or is this referencing the log function within the same script?

Comment: Yes, `xargs` cannot call shell functions because it's not built into the shell, so I needed to export it to file. If that's really unacceptable, then you can always replace `xargs` with a `while read` loop.